# Resistance for relay coil

Tags: relay

I'm going to use a 5V relay ( DIP05-1A72-12D [Datasheet](http://datasheet.octopart.com/DIP05-1A72-12L-MEDER-datasheet-11762223.pdf)), and my supply voltage is 5V, do I need a resistance in series with the relay coil not to burn the relay?

Answer (score 2):

The direct answer is that you do not need a resistance in series when powering a 5 volt relay coil from 5 volt power supply.
   --  For more in depth understanding, go to the data sheet that you linked, and look at the coil data. -- From the coil data, you can calculate the amount of current required for the coil. 
   ---- Lots of in depth analysis can be made depending upon how you drive the relay coil.

Answer (score 2):

Marla answered your question (+1). One caution is that the model you have incorporates a catch diode, and if you get the polarity backward you will experience some "burning" type symptoms.

Comment: good catch Spehro. It is always the little details that will get ya. Also, not all of the relays shown have the diode.